# Match more than entry according to the occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `Source` sheet (that has the data in 7 columns and the main column to be matched is column A) and the second sheet is `Target` where I need to deal with column C to search for the items existing and show the results according to the occurrences.
I have put a simple example to explain the issue and to make it better to see the expected output
This is `Source` sheet
[image]

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header5 Header6 Header7
101     H2_1    H3_1    H4_1    H5_1    H6_1    H7_1
102     H2_2    H3_2    H4_2    H5_2    H6_2    H7_2
103     H2_3    H3_3    H4_3    H5_3    H6_3    H7_3
102     H2_4    H3_4    H4_4    H5_4    H6_4    H7_4
101     H2_5    H3_5    H4_5    H5_5    H6_5    H7_5
103     H2_6    H3_6    H4_6    H5_6    H6_6    H7_6
105     H2_7    H3_7    H4_7    H5_7    H6_7    H7_7
104     H2_8    H3_8    H4_8    H5_8    H6_8    H7_8
```

And this is the expected output
[image]

A friend could help me with a formula but I need to use VBA code (preferring arrays)

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Source!$B$2:$G$9,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$3:$C$11)-2/($C3=Source!$A$2:$A$9),MOD((ROW($A1)-1),COUNTIF($C$3:$C$11,$C3))+1),MATCH(Target!D$2,Source!$B$1:$G$1,0)),"")
```

Comment: Copy and paste data in the post with image so that we can copy and paste to excel. Do you have `Office365`?

Comment: Updated. Yes I have office 365 but I need to do that using code.

Comment: Should we understand that **only** column C:C exists in 'Target' sheet, like we can see it in the picture?

Comment: Yes column C is there and the code should match according to it but to be careful about the multiple occurrences

Comment: What if more occurrences then lines in 'Target' worksheet?

Comment: More instances would be left empty as shown for the third occurrence of 101

Comment: I meant more occurrences in 'Source' sheet then lines (for the same code) in 'Target' one...

Comment: The code must be restricted in search to the values in Target sheet in column C as a base for the search process so no matter how many occurrences in Source sheet.

Comment: When you answer one of my questions, please tag me (@FaneDuru). Otherwise, I am not notified about your comment. I do not follow only your question... I can start preparing a piece of code only after everything is clear in my mind. One last question: Can the number of occurrences in 'Source' sheet be more then three?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes in the Source sheet there is no limit in data.

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer. I started something, but I needed some more pieces of information...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks a lot for your interest in this topic.

Comment: Please, test my answer code and send some feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It assumes that the 'Source' sheet (named "Source") has data do be processed in the range A2:G - last row in column A:A and 'Target' sheet keeps the range to be processed in the range C3:C - last row in column C:C:

```
Sub testMatchEntries()
 Dim shS As Worksheet, shT As Worksheet, lastRS As Long, lastRT As Long
 Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, arrS As Variant, arrT As Variant, arrInt As Variant
 Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrExcl As Variant, k As Long, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
 Dim iRow As Long, R As Long, arrHeaders As Variant
 
 Set shS = Worksheets("Source") 'use here your sheet, please
 Set shT = Worksheets("Target") 'use here your sheet, please
 lastRS = shS.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 lastRT = shT.Range("C" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 shT.Range("D3:H" & lastRT).ClearContents 'clear the previous run filled cells
 arrS = shS.Range("A2:G" & lastRS).value  'put the necessary range in an array
 arrT = shT.Range("C3:F" & lastRT).value  'put the necessary range in an array
 'Collect the headers to be passed in the Source worksheet
 arrHeaders = Array(shS.Range("C1").value, shS.Range("D1").value, shS.Range("G1").value)
 
 ReDim arrExcl(UBound(arrT) - 1) 'create an array to exclude the already used elements
 For i = 1 To UBound(arrT)
    For Each El In arrExcl
        If El = arrT(i, 1) Then GoTo OverProcessing 'exclude the processed element for the next iteration
    Next
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrS)
        If arrT(i, 1) = arrS(j, 1) Then
            boolFound = True 'a match has been found
            If Not dict.Exists(arrT(i, 1)) Then 'fill data in a dictionary if not already esists
                dict.Add arrT(i, 1), arrS(j, 3) & ":" & arrS(j, 4) & ":" & arrS(j, 7) & "|1"
            Else
                'add new ranges when they are found and increment the occurrences number (last elem)
                arrInt = Split(dict(arrT(i, 1)), "|")
                dict(arrT(i, 1)) = arrInt(0) & ";" & arrS(j, 3) & ":" & _
                        arrS(j, 4) & ":" & arrS(j, 7) & "|" & CLng(arrInt(1)) + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    If boolFound Then
        iRow = Split(dict(arrT(i, 1)), "|")(1)              'extract the number of rows

       arrInt = Split(Split(dict(arrT(i, 1)), "|")(0), ";") 'split the dict item to determine each row
       For R = 0 To iRow - 1
           arrT(i + R, 2) = Split(arrInt(R), ":")(0)        'fill the array values according to their row
           arrT(i + R, 3) = Split(arrInt(R), ":")(1)
           arrT(i + R, 4) = Split(arrInt(R), ":")(2)
       Next
    End If
    boolFound = False 'reinitialize the variable.
                      'Without it, trying to split a null string an error will occur
    arrExcl(k) = arrT(i, 1): k = k + 1 'load the processed element in the exclusions array
OverProcessing:
 Next i
 shT.Range("F2:H2").value = arrHeaders 'drop the headers
 Dim sliceArray As Variant 'dim a new array to keep a slice from arrT one
 'nice line to slice a 2D array without iteration...
 sliceArray = Application.Index(arrT, Evaluate("row(1:" & UBound(arrT, 1) & ")"), _
                                                    Evaluate("COLUMN(" & "B:D" & ")"))
 'drop the processed (sliced) array:
 shT.Range("E3").Resize(UBound(sliceArray, 1), UBound(sliceArray, 2)).value = sliceArray
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

It returns in the range "E2:H" last row in column "C:C". If, after testing everything runs as you need, you can change the range where to return, even to rewrite column C:C...

Comment: That's wonderful. Can I exclude the column C from the results when po[ulating the output array? I just the need the output to be separarted from the column C.

Comment: @YasserKhalil: Yes, but the simplest way for this solution will be to let the code deliver how it does and only delete the column in discussion. I will adapt the code to do that. I forgot to mention about the reference to 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime', but if you could test it, this means you understood what is it about... **Adapted**.  Is this what you need?

Comment: I mean to let the column C as it is without touching it and get only the results as an array as you did but without column C

Comment: @YasserKhalil: But doesn't it deliver exactly what you are saying? I mean, after deletion of the D:D column (in code). If I would know about this, let us say, request, I would design the code in a different way. Another array to deliver the processing result should be necessary, and the existing one will be limited to only one column. I made the code more efficient using the same array. If I will adapt it in this way, it will take me almost the same time, being a new design. Now I have to leave the office. I can also try slicing the existing array, but when I will be at home...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: @YasserKhalil: I adapted the code to cut the necessary slice from the processed array (a nice piece of code in a line - without iteration) and drop only the data loaded in the array slice. I passed by a friend, for short time and I couldn't resist to not put in practice the idea I had in mind... He supplied his laptop and here it is the solution. :)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much for the great efforts.

Comment: @YasserKhalil: Welcome! No special effort. I like putting my ideas in code, if what is to be done is clear enough...